# Reading numbers from row in python csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to export only certain lines with specific criteria from a large csv file... I keep getting an error when looking for lines with a certain rating in row 13. The ratings are whole numbers and half decimals (example below).

Ratings 
5 
4.5 
3 
1 
4 
4 
3.5

Here is my code...

```
import csv
citys = [ 
raw_input ("Enter City Name:"),
] 
states = [ 
raw_input ("Enter State Name:"),
] 
categorys = [ 
'Auto Repair',
] 
ratings = [ 
'5',
]

listname = raw_input ("Enter List Name:")
listname_accept = (listname) + '.csv'

with open('master.csv', 'r') as master, open((listname_accept), 'w') as matched:
        reader = csv.reader(master)
        writer = csv.writer(matched)
        writer.writerow(next(reader))
        for row in reader:
                if row[5] in citys and row[6] in states and row[2] in categorys and row[13] in ratings:
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

When I run it, It only prints the header row. I know row 13 is correct and there definitely are lines that match.

Here is an example csv...

```
url,name,category,display_address,street,city,state_code,postal_code,neighborhood,cross_street,phone,website,review,rating
www.url.com,Business 1,Auto Repair,"123 Any St., City, State, 12345",123 Any St,City,State,12345,Long Island City,None,999-999-9999,www.website.com,18,5
www.url.com,Business 2,"Auto Repair , Body Shops , Towing","123 Any St., City, State, 12345",123 Any St,City,State,12345,Long Island City,None,999-999-9999,www.website.com,67,4.5
www.url.com,Business 3,Auto Repair,"123 Any St., City, State, 12345",123 Any St,City,State,12345,Long Island City,None,999-999-9999,www.website.com,14,5
www.url.com,Business 3,"Body Shops , Auto Repair","123 Any St., City, State, 12345",123 Any St,City,State,12345,Long Island City,None,999-999-9999,www.website.com,14,1.5
```

Disregarding the other criteria, ideally, it should return "Business 1" and "Business 3".

Comment: I can't comment. Can you post the csv (or a sample csv) so I can have a look for you? I'll edit the post (or delete it) with an appropriate answer.

Comment: Well, it looks like at least one of the four things you expect to match isn't. Step one would be to figure out which one(s). Then it should be easier to figure out why.

Comment: @arlyon I have edited and added an example csv.

Comment: @glibdud It works perfect if I remove the `and row[13] in ratings` part. As soon as I put that in, it only writes the header row.

Comment: Then I guess the next thing would be to print out `row[13]` and the values in `ratings` (in a way that would preserve any leading/trailing whitespace) and see why they're not matching.

Comment: @glibdud Thanks for your help. Once I printed the row, I found that `5` was actually printed as `5.0`. Same for `4` and `4.0`. I believe I have it working now

Comment: @glibdud Rookie mistake...